# Ошибка с наследованием в Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

У меня есть класс `BasicHandler`, который не является абстрактным. Я наследуюсь от него при создании класса `Checker` с таким вот конструктором:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
```

Класс `Checker` я сделал абстрактным (возможно в этом и заключается проблема?) вот так:

```
__metaclass__ = ABCMeta
```

Далее я создаю конкретный класс `SpecialChecker` с конструктором:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
```

В результате, при запуске скрипта с созданием объекта типа `SpecialChecker` получаю:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

**В чем может быть дело ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, но конструкцию вида

```
super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
```

не стоит использовать, т.к.  `self.__class__` будет одинаковым во всех базовых классах, соответственно Вы и получаете бесконечную рекурсию.

```
    class C(object):
        def __init__(self):
            print(self.__class__)
            super(self.__class__, self).__init__()


    class D(C):
        def __init__(self):
            print(self.__class__)
            super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

    d = D()
    print d
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class BasicHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):pass
    def foo(self):pass
    def bar(self):pass


class Checker(BasicHandler):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # ok
        # super(self.__class__, self).__init__()  # RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
        self.foo()


class SpecialChecker(Checker):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.foo()

SpecialChecker()
```